# How do I replace characters in a string using a character map?

Tags: python, dictionary

### Code purpose:

I provide a string and match it with dictionary keys; if the key and string match I print the dictionary values.

### Here's the code:

```
def to_rna(dna_input):
    dna_rna = {'A':'U', 'C':'G', 'G':'C', 'T':'A'}
    rna = []
    for key in dna_rna.iterkeys():
        if key in dna_input:
            rna.append(dna_rna[key])
    print "".join(rna)

to_rna("ACGTGGTCTTAA") #the string input
```

### Problem:

The result should be '**UGCACCAGAAUU**' but all I get is '**UGAC**'. The problem appears to be that I have duplicate characters in the string and the loop is ignoring this. How do I loop through the dictionary so that it returns the dictionary value as many times as the dict key is found?

Comment: The loop should be `for char in dna_input` instead of iterating the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: Then append the corresponding value of each of these characters that appear in the string.

Comment: Lastly, join them as you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output a character for every character in `dna_input` you need to iterate over character in `dna_input`. Note that the `get()` function provides a default for characters that aren't in your dictionary. I am replacing with nothing, if desired you could put an `n` here, or an X.

```
rna.append(dna_rna.get(char, 'n'))
```

Your code was only iterating over the 4 entries in the `dna_rna` dictionary.

```
def to_rna(dna_input):
    dna_rna = {'A':'U', 'C':'G', 'G':'C', 'T':'A'}
    rna = []
    for char in dna_input:
        rna.append(dna_rna.get(char, ''))
    print "".join(rna)

to_rna("ACGTGGTCTTAA") #the string input
```

However, this isn't the most efficient way to translate a string.

Comment: Or use `dna_rna.get(char, '')`

Comment: This question only warrants a comment, because proper iteration is answer in the tutorials.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi A question is either worth an answer, or it should be closed. This one can be answered. As a side note, the choice of making _three_ comments in a row is also debatable.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem and makes the most sense. I am only just getting to grips with Python so apologies if the question was silly!

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).  Edit: I added the regex to return `-` for bad entries (seemed like a good idea @jh44tx had):

```
import string
import re
rna_trans = string.maketrans("ACGTU","UGCA-")
rna_trans = re.sub("[^UGCA]","-",rna_trans)
print "ACGTGGTCTTAA".translate(rna_trans)
```

Since the mappings are 1:1 you can also create a reverse translate:

```
rev_rna_trans = string.maketrans("UGCAT","ACGT-")
rev_rna_trans = re.sub("[^ACGT]","-",rna_trans)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you think you'll get junk letters sometimes, you can do this:

```
def to_rna(dna_input):
    dna_rna={'A':'U','C':'G','G':'C','T':'A'}
    rna=[]
    for char in dna_input:
        if char in dna_rna.keys():
            rna.append(dna_rna[char])
        else:
            rna.append('-')
    print "".join(rna)

to_rna("ACGTGGTCTTAAX")
```

and the result is:
**UGCACCAGAAUU-**

Comment: Good job thinking about the junk letters.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that each letter of the input will be translated to an output string, you're better off making a loop over each letter:

```
def to_rna(dna_input):
    dna_rna = {'A':'U', 'C':'G', 'G':'C', 'T':'A'}
    rna = []
    for x in dna_input:
        rna.append(dna_rna[x])
    return ''.join(rna)
```

or you could write it with list comprehensions

```
def to_rna(dna_input):
    dna_rna = {'A':'U', 'C':'G', 'G':'C', 'T':'A'}
    return ''.join([dna_rna[x] for x in dna_input])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as a list comprehension. Because this becomes a one-liner it pretty much makes the function superfluous:

```
def to_rna(dna_input):
    dna_rna = {'A':'U', 'C':'G', 'G':'C', 'T':'A'}
    return "".join([dna_rna.get(x, '') for x in dna_input])
```